# DataReader.Read() skips first row of recordset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datareader

I am trying to check the value of a field before decided what to input into a drop down list in ASP.net.

I am using datareader.Read() in order to read the recordset so I can do this. However this then skips the first row of data . . The drop down box is basically a list of sizes and colours . . . So currently I am missing the first size.

Here is the code:

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand("doGetAllSizesForProduct", oConn)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", CType(Request.QueryString("id"), Integer))
  oConn.Open()
  Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows() = True Then
      dr.Read()
      ddlSize.Visible = True
      pnlSize.Visible = True
      pnlNoStock.Visible = False
      If dr("colour") = "None" Then
        ddlSize.DataTextField = "size"
      Else
        ddlSize.DataTextField = "sizeColour"
      End If                    
      ddlSize.DataValueField = "mapperid"
      ddlSize.DataSource = dr
      ddlSize.DataBind()
    Else
    End If
    dr.Close()
  End Using
End Using
```

I guess either there must be another method other than Read or a way to stop it skipping the first record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen a datareader being used as the datasource.  What I think is happening is that your first call to `dr.Read()` is skipping to the first record as expected.  However, when you assign the reader as the datasource, it's doing its own `dr.Read()` logic inside which starts at the next record.  This could explain why you're not seeing the first item.  Try modifying your code like this to use a DataTable instead (warning, didn't test this):

```
using dr as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if dr.HasRows() then
        ddlSize.Visible = True 
        pnlSize.Visible = True 
        pnlNoStock.Visible = False 

        While dr.Read()
            dim Value as string = dr("mapperid")
            dim Text as string = if(dr("colour") = "None",dr("size"),dr("sizeColour"))
            ddlSize.Items.Add(New ListItem(Text, Value))
        End While
    end if
    dr.Close()
end using
```

Comment: oscilatingcretin, that is very close to what I need, the only problem is, it does not work row by row to work out if that rows colour = "None", only the row you select. How would I make it work out this on a row by row basis, thanks for your help so far

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  The above code basically works exactly the same as your code, but with a datatable instead of a reader.  Your original code was only making one call to `dr.Read()`, so it would have only worked for one iteration anyway.  For starters, does my solution at least populate your dropdown with all data?

Comment: The above code does populate my drop down. However if the first value for instance is "Medium Red" then it shows the size and colour for each itteration, so even if the second value was "Medium None" then it will show "Medium None" rather than just "Medium" because it does not carry out the check on every itteration. Similarly if the first value was "Medium None" then it would show as "Medium" but the second value of "Medium Red" would also only show as "Medium". I basically just need to evaluate it on every itteration, rather than just row 0. Thanks for your help so far, very much appreciated

Comment: Afraid I am now recieving this: 
"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the doGetAllSizesForProduct stored procedure to return two recordsets?

The first recordset can return a single row giving an indication of what type of data is contained in the second recordset, which contains the same content as previously.

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to use the `DataReader` like this, executing a single `Read` to get the value in the first record then binding the UI control to it like this:

```
ddlSize.DataValueField = "mapperid"
ddlSize.DataSource = dr
ddlSize.DataBind()
```

I would personally use a `DataTable` for binding to a UI control, or try to remove the call to  `dr.Read()` and see how it works.